# using mouse as paint brush

Tags: c++, opencv

So this is my attempt at setting MouseEvent in openCV, my point is to draw some thing at given point according to mouse event. Any idea what's wrong?
I followed this tutorials: https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/db/d5b/tutorial_py_mouse_handling.html

```
        #include<opencv2\core\core.hpp>
        #include<opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
        #include<opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
        #include<opencv2\ml\ml.hpp>
        #include<iostream>
        #include<conio.h>
        using namespace std;
        using namespace cv;
        int radius = 5;
        Mat img;
        int ix = 1;
        int iy = 1;
        //mouse callback function
        void drawCircle(int event, int x, int y, int, void* param) {
            if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
            {
                cout << "x = " << x
                    << "\t y = " << y
                    << endl;
                circle(img, Point(x, y), 10, Scalar(255,255,255), 10);
            }
            //line(img, Point(10, 10), Point(x, y), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3);
        }
        int main() {
            img = imread("image.png");
            if (img.empty()) {
                cout << "\nerror reading image" << endl;
                _getch();
                return -1;
            }
            namedWindow("Image",1);
            imshow("Image", img);
            setMouseCallback("Image", drawCircle);
            waitKey(0);
            return 0;
        }
```

Why doesn't it draw circle or line on my image? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to force a redraw of the window to reflect the changes. I.e. replace your waitKey(0) by something like:

```
while (waitKey(20) != 27)  // wait until ESC is pressed
{
    imshow("Image", img);
}
```

Alternatively, you may be able to just add a call to imshow to the drawCircle callback.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sadly I don't have enough priviledge to upvote your answer. I made it by changing to waitKey(20) != 27 (ESC), your code just made the window close immediately. Still thank so much for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to your fix. Don't worry about votes :-)